# Database ER diagram review. Is this a good database design ? [HELP]

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

This database For school management system.

Please review and help me with your ideas.

[image]

Comment: can you explain on the concept

Comment: ^This. For example, what's the purpose of `Blood_grouping` in a School Management System?

Comment: @J.D. Blood_grouping -> in case of emergency or accident

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! For starters, Make sure that you're legally covered with respect to blood types - it's fairly personal information and I'm just wondering whether you have all the necessary documentation/procedures for storing it. Schema design is an [iterative process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process) - 1) start with a design, 2) code against it, 3) fix bugs & redesign, 4) go back to 1! I'd suggest that you come back to us when you have more **specific** problems - it's virtually impossible to glance at a schema and say, yes, that works...

Comment: @Vérace Thanks sir

Comment: Just few additional questions and nitpicks:
A) Can someone (Student, Parent or Teacher) have more than one Role? (What do roles even mean?)
B) Teacher should probably be able to teach more than one Class.
C) It feels there should be some relation(s) between Student and Class.
D) Is Class single lesson (_Statistics 101 tought at 15:30 2021-04-07 in classroom 213_)? Single course (_Statistics 101 taught on winter semester of academic year 2021/2022_)?
E) I wouldn't store the Age in DB, but calculate it from Date of birth on the spot every time I query the table, because it tends to change.

Comment: F) I wouldn't store Phone as `INT`, but rather `VARCHAR(20)`. You never use numeric operations on phone numbers - they are more alike _phone addresses_ or _phone codes_. Also, INT has max. value of  2,147,483,647 => no phone numbers with more than 10 digits. And what about numbers formatted with various non-numeric characters?
G) If the Presence table is supposed(?) to capture whether particular Student was attending particular Lesson belonging to certain Course taught by concrete Teacher, then there should be some relations to other involved entities.

Comment: @IvanLoginov Thanks for this very helpful piece of information.